# jquery mobile manually invoke page plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I need to know how to do this.

Right now it is loading pages into the same page when I am not on a phone(handheld) device.
Thus, I will need some conditions to be tested, same as the media query's.
for example: test if some element is hidden and only then invoke the plugin

I don't know if this would work better then a page redirect, but I will have to see?

**How can I do that?**

jquery mobile is only needed for small screen usage( handhelds). The media query's work ok.
The way I set it up is that it hides everything on the page and shows only the mobile part.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 555px),
screen and (max-device-width: 480px)
{ 
#wrap,#footer,#masker{display:none;}
#p-mobi{ display:block;}
}
```

and

```
<div data-role="page" id="p-mobi">

</div>
```

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few available options.

According to your needs this one should be the best one:

1. https://github.com/borismus/device.js

   This is completely client side detection, no need for custom js scripting just use this custom link tag and match it to the desired device size.

   For example:

   ```
   <link rel="alternate" href="http://foo.com" id="desktop" media="only screen and (touch-enabled: 0)">
   <link rel="alternate" href="http://m.foo.com" id="phone" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 640px)">
   <link rel="alternate" href="http://tablet.foo.com" id="tablet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 641px)">
   ```

   More can be found here: https://github.com/borismus/device.js
2. Or use [this](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) script to detect a browser type and then use this js loader to decide which js file should be used.

   Example:

   ```
   yepnope({
       test : Modernizr.geolocation,
       yep  : 'normal.js',
       nope : ['polyfill.js', 'wrapper.js']
   });
   ```

   One more thing yephope.js is not out of the box compatible with jQuery so you will need to do a little [fix](http://scott.donnel.ly/yepnope-jquery-document-ready/).

My advice, stick with the option 1.

Comment: thanks, I adjusted my question a little, but the gist is the same. I will try the first one, the second does not seem to be all that usefull because it only tests browser capabilitys.

Comment: You are correct but it is still better then using js to detect device type and manually load additional content. First option will do just that without code overhead. Only down side is it don't work on IE7 and below but that is not a big problem.

Comment: I am reading it on github... don't understand why he is mentioning modernizr.mq or is he borrowing code from modernizr?

Comment: You are correct about borrowing, you dont need to include yourself. Lets call it a wrapper around a part of modernizr.